# Date and time input

Tags: php, mysql, html, date, time

How can I show a date popup box that formats the date so it will fit in the mySQL date field?

Also, how can I check or format time to fit in the mySQL time field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );
$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );
```

edit:

This and Everything else about date/time in PHP, and how to use it with MySQL, is in the wonderful PHP documentation:

http://be.php.net/datetime

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for some kind of widget to allow the user to enter date & time.  See this [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576524/recommend-a-js-calendar-widget-that-handles-both-date-and-time).